# What holiday is "Miss All Sunday" named after?

Tags: one-piece

In Baroque works, the strongest 14 male members (including the unluckies) are named after numbers:  Mr. 13, Mr. 12, Mr. 11 ... Mr. 0.

The female counterparts for Mr. 13 through Mr. 8 are named: Miss Friday, Miss Saturday, Miss Thursday, Miss Tuesday, Miss Wednesday, and Miss Monday.

From then on, they are named after holidays: Miss Fathers Day, Miss Mothers Day, Miss Valentine, Miss Merry Christmas, Miss Golden Week, Bon Kurei/Bon Clay (don't ask), and Miss Double Finger (New Years Day).

The final female, however, is Miss All-Sunday who is Nico Robin. What is "All-Sunday" referring to?  Is it a holiday?  If it is just meant to be Sunday, why is the "All" there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a holiday. In his answer in Vol#18 SBS, Oda-sensei clearly said that "All Sunday" means "All the Sundays". In some English translations, translators add "of the year" but this isn't mentioned in the [original Japanese text.](http://onepmanianetabare.web.fc2.com/sbs/sbs18.html)

(My translation of said SBS)

```
Reader:
Hello! Odatchi! I noticed something amazing! It's about Mr. 2
Bon Kurei. It's why only Mr. 2 Bon Kurei has this codename! Numbers
are for males, but Bon Kurei is for a female which means "the end of
Bon" because he is an okama, right?

Oda:
Yes, that's right. Female agents' names are in order of the happiest events, so first:
No. 0 is All Sunday (All the Sundays)
No. 1 is Double Finger (New Year's Day)
No. 2 is Mr. 2 Bon Kurei (End of Bon)
No. 3 is Golden Week (Golden Week)
No. 4 if Christmas (Christmas)

.....something like that. Everyone seems to be puzzled with Double Finger.
```

Note: There is an illustration of both index fingers raised showing 1 and 1 (1/1 or January 1).

<strike>Only the author, Oda-sensei knows what "All Sunday" means, but many Japanese-speaking fans think that it means "everyday is Sunday", while a few others think "all Sundays of the year".</strike>

Comment: Double Finger doesn't sound like a holiday... it is Oda's personal joke about him pointing up two fingers to represent the date 1/1.  I doubt many people would have guessed that. Therefore, it All Sunday could well be a joke of Oda's  only he gets.... bummer.   Is there any source you have found for the Japanese interpretations or someone asking Oda or is that from personal experience?

Comment: @kaine I just re-checked the SBS and revised my answer.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, this means Sunday. On the wiki her alias name is known as Miss Sunday for the Dubbed version. This would be both to simplify it and it also still holds meaning.
Overall, Miss All Sunday is also known as Miss Sunday.

[Source](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Nico_Robin)

Comment: You mean the 4Kids dub? No offense but i really dont consider that canon. https://youtu.be/_GARfy90meA.  It would simplify things though.

Comment: yeah. the 4Kids dub. Personally, I hate dub and only watch subbed. In all honesty, I think that Miss All Sunday can also be known as Miss Sunday. What's your take on this @kaine

Comment: The issue isnt dub vs. sub. The issue is that one particular company's treatment of the material.  I think you may be right but 4Kids isnt a reliable source.

Comment: understandable. Sorry, however, also how can we explain the female agent's name in that random order... Miss Friday, Miss Saturday, Miss Thursday, Miss Tuesday, Miss Wednesday, and Miss Monday then to the holidays? @kaine